# Computer is not detecting any wireless signal

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, router

I have recently acquired a new laptop, and my old laptop was too old to sell for any significant value. I decided to put the eight gigs to use on my old laptop and installed 12.04 on an eight gig DVD. I successfully ran Ubuntu on the computer, but I could not connect to my wireless Internet connection. When clicking on the top-right network symbol, it says "No network devices available".

When typing `iwconfig` into terminal, the result is

```
lo       no wireless extensions.
```

With `sudo lshw -C network`, the result is

```
*-network
    description: Network controller
    product: BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
    version: 01
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
    resources: irq:17 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
```

My new laptop can connect to my router wirelessly perfectly. I have connected my Raspberry Pi to my laptop through connecting my Pi to my computer with an ethernet cable. I am prepared to do the same with this new laptop as it is right next to it. I am not willing to, however, connect my laptop to the router.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix wifi problems using two methods:

```
Either connect to the internet via wired connection and run this command:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot your system.

```
Or use the following commands:

sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package

sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl* firmware-b43-lpphy-installer b43-fwcutter
```

Finally, reboot your system.

If that didn't help, try these commands:

sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter

sudo reboot

Comment: +user226009 Thank you for your response but I cannot use sudo apt-get because I don't have any Internet. Also, I cannot connect my laptop via wired connection or I would not be asking this question...